# sed: replace newline within <p> </p> with space

Tags: linux, shell, sed

Let's say I have the file: index.html

index.html

```html
<p class="p">This
entry will determine the number of transmit threads, each channel
represents one thread, which can handle multiple multicast ports.
All channels are enabled by default. To temporarily disable a particular
channel, use the folowing configuration lines:</p>
```

How can i replace newline to space within

tag only

For example, changing index.html to:

```html
<p class="p">This entry will determine the number of transmit threads, each channel represents one thread, which can handle multiple multicast ports. All channels are enabled by default. To temporarily disable a particular channel, use the folowing configuration lines:</p>`
```

Tried with,

```bash
sed -e "/<p>/s/\n/ /g" index.html
```

not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `gnu-sed`:

```bash
sed -E '/<p class="p">/{:a; N; s/\n/ /g; /<\/p>/!ba;}' index.html
```

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` code. Using `awk`'s paragraph mode in Record separator.

```bash
awk -v RS=  '
match($0,/(^|\n)\<p .*\<\/p\>/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  gsub(/\n/," ",val)
  print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) val substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
}
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

With sed (which may not work on all platforms): `sed -i.bak 's/\n$/ /g' index.html`. Note that sed will backup your file before performing changes here.

Instead of sed, you can use the `tr` as follow: `tr '\n' ' '`.

Comment: What do you mean "there is no \n"?